# Render a plain text as html in a callback in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a reusable table component that we can define the columns to display. The following is the definition of this column.

```
  {
    columnDef: 'action',
    header: 'Action',
    cell: ColumnTypeEnum.ActionColumn,
    options: {
      template: ['approve', 'cancel', 'print', 'inline-edit', 'view', 'delete'],
      buttons: {
        approve: (element: any) => {
          return `<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="approve/${element.id}" color="primary">
              <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
            </a>`;
        },
        cancel: (element: any) => {
          return `<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="cancel/${element.id}" color="warn">
              <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon>
            </a>`;
        },
        print: (element: any) => {
          return `<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="print/${element.id}" color="primary">
              <mat-icon>print</mat-icon>
            </a>`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

And I created a component to process those column configuration as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-column',
  templateUrl: './action-column.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action-column.component.scss'],
})
export class ActionColumnComponent {
  @Input() element!: ModelInterface;
  @Input() isInModeRowEditable: boolean = false;
  @Input() withRowInlineEdit: boolean = true;
  @Input() options: any;

  @Output() readonly displayDeleteConfirmation = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() readonly toggleRowInlineEdit = new EventEmitter();

  confirmDelete(element: any) {
    this.displayDeleteConfirmation.emit(element);
  }

  inlineEditableRowToggle(element: any) {
    this.toggleRowInlineEdit.emit(element);
  }
}
```

And here is the html at `/action-column.component.html`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let action of options.template">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="action">
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'inline-edit'">
        <app-inline-edit-row
          [element]="element"
          [withRowInlineEdit]="withRowInlineEdit"
          (toggleRowInlineEdit)="inlineEditableRowToggle($event)"
        />
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'view'">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="view"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'update'">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="update"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'delete'">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="delete"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
        <ng-container *ngIf="options.buttons[action]; else errorCustomAction">
          {{ options.buttons[action](element) }}
        </ng-container>

        <ng-template #errorCustomAction>
          <small> {{ action }} is undefined in `buttons` element </small>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

The problem that arises is when calling callbacks on buttons. `{{ options.buttons[action](element) }}`.

Instead of the HTML element being 'rendered', a plain string is displayed in the browser:

```
<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="approve/934870" color="primary"> <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon> </a> 

<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="cancel/934870" color="warn"> <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon> </a> 

<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="print/934870" color="primary"> <mat-icon>print</mat-icon> </a>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For security reasons this is the correct behavior and you should expect this from professional software. But to solve you problem you should not defined the angular tags in the string but the data (icon, color, routerling) and render the tags as usually.

Comment: You can **NOT** render "angular components or directives". (to render html you need use innerHTML and sanitize the html text). Re-think your problem to create the components in the .html